# Support Ticket Module

Tags: 6

Okay, I know that there a quite a few modules that the suit the title that seem to be obvious, but none of them seem to do what I really want. I'm using Drupal 6 for my business website and I'm using Ubercart to sell my product (it's actually a software company). I also want to offer a support ticketing system.

I don't really want to expose any email addresses, I want to be able to allow any staff to see all of the support tickets that have been submitted, and the first staff to see a ticket and answer it gets assigned to the ticket, like normal. I really like the support system that is used on real-debrid.com/support, but solutions like osTicket and ZenDesk seem okay - if only they integrated with Drupal 6.

So if anybody has any suggestions as to what I can use as a support ticket, I would appreciate it if you could tell  me.

By the way, in case somebody asks I'm using Drupal 6 rather than Drupal 7 because some of the modules that I need to be use are only available for Drupal 6.

**The Modules That I have looked at** include:

- Support - which you have to configure clients for; that makes it not suitable
- Storm - which has too many options when submitting the ticket
- UC Ticket - which I think only works using emails, which I don't want
- Case Tracker - doesn't seem quite like it's meant for the job

Comment: you seem to have already ruled out a number of the drupal support ticketing modules that are available but are also asking for other drupal support suggestions, correct? If so - what drupal modules have you looked at and passed on so we can avoid recommending those again.

Comment: You're right. Please see my edited answer! Though, I do fear that I have overlooked and thought that somebody might suggest a module and the options to configure it how I would like.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for adding these, though you have already ruled out one of my favorites (support) ;) One thought - trying to replicate the power and flexibility of one of the commercial solutions like ZenDesk (another favorite) is probably going to require a lot of customization of one of these above modules. I like "Support" as an option because I've found it to be a lot easier to develop piecemeal to meet specific client needs.

Comment: Also - one benefit of using something like ZenDesk is that it does not integrate with Drupal and lives on a separate server / infrastructure so if catastrophe strikes, your client base has at least one channel where they can still reach you and get updates, submit requests, etc.

Comment: No ploblem. The only thing with the Support module is, as I say, that I'd have to create a new client for every customer - which I do not want to do. I do appreciate that there's is a reason why solutions like ZenDesk only do one job and why there is limited modules with the functionality out there. I also see what you see about keeping the two separate, and I do keep going back to osTicket (I can't afford to pay for a solution) - I just need it too look like my website!

Comment: there's also [civi crm](http://civicrm.org/go/download), but probably to hugh for your needs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I guess no one else is going to answer this question, so I've devised my own solution now based on schnippy's helpful answers! Basically, I've decided to use osTicket seeing as though it is a complete solution and I don't think I'll ever find a comparable Drupal Module, not for a long time anyway!

I'm actually quite surprised as well. I've managed to make it look completely the same as the Drupal website and it was considerably easy, especially considering I didn't really know the theme coding...

So there you go. If you're ever in the same boat as me I'd fully recommend osTicket -  it is free but very extensive and flexible. Perfect for my business!